# Random string from an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm kind of new to C, but not to programming. I'm trying to create a program that takes an input and replies with a random string that's already saved in an array (for example).

I'm not trying to create a random string, I want them to be "fixed", like in Java:

```
String [] sa; 
sa[0] = "Hello, World"; 
sa[1] = "Hi dude!";
```

Comment: Do you have a program that takes an input and replies with a "random" fixed string all the time?

Comment: Yes, my problem was to hardcode my answers and to Randomize it

Comment: `printf("%s\n", sa[rand() % 2]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char *messages[] = {
        "Hello!",
        "How are you?",
        "Good stuff!"
    };
    const size_t messages_count = sizeof(messages) / sizeof(messages[0]);
    char input[64];
    while (1) {
        scanf("%63s", input);
        printf("%s\n", messages[rand() % messages_count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const char *sa[]={"Hello, World","Hi dude!"};
```

Then you can do

```
return sa[i];
```

The return value is `char *`
Just make sure **i** is within bounds

Comment: `const char *sa[]` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear as to what you exactly want, but here is a brief description of how strings work in C.

There are no String like data type in C as you have in Java. You have to use array of characters. For an array of strings, you have to use two dimensional array of characters.

```
char myStrings[MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what your are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char buffer[42];
    const char *mytext[] = {"A1", "A2", "A3"};
    scanf("%41s", buffer);
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Random text: %s\n", mytext[rand() % (sizeof(mytext) / sizeof(mytext[0]))]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#include<stdio.h>`
`#include<stdlib.h>`
`int main(){`
`char str[7][100]={"hello1","hello2","hello3","hello4","hello5","hello6","hello7"};`
`printf("%s",str[rand()%7]);`
`return 0;`
`}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).